# Unable to set GPU memory split on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, memory, config.txt, gpu, memory-split

I have looked everywhere (both on and off StackExchange) for this but cannot get an answer:

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W, which has 512MB of RAM total.  I am running it headless, so I want to maximize available RAM.  I have set `gpu_mem=16` in the `\boot\config.txt` file and have rebooted the device.

When I run `free -h` I get the following output:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           370M         20M        299M        2.6M         50M        300M`

When I run `vcgencmd get_mem arm && vcgencmd get_mem gpu` I get:

`arm=384M
gpu=128M`

This seems to be telling me that the GPU memory is still set to 128MB.

How can I properly free up this memory for general use by my applications?

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can give here.

Comment: Have you installed the official `Raspbian` image or the `NOOBS` image on your miniSD card?  Are there any `hdmi_` configuration options in your `/boot/config.txt` ?  I believe the default `gpu_mem` is 64M not 128M.

Comment: That's strange, considering it works perfectly as expected on my Pi Zero W, even if I go all out with the `hdmi_*` options. To ensure that it isn't an issue of formatting or a CRLF in your `/boot/config.txt`, does the problem persist if you enact the change via `sudo raspi-config`?

Comment: RubberStamp - I am on Raspbian 'Stretch' as of the time of this writing with all of the firmware up-to-date.  All `hdmi_` entries in `/boot/config.txt` are commented out (this is a completely headless install). The `gpu_mem` setting is `16` (the minimum).

Comment: jdonald - I tried updating the GPU split via `raspi-config` just to be sure, and  everything is still coming up the same, so it's not a formatting issue.

Comment: is the value the same in `raspi-config` and in `config.txt` file ?

Comment: Guy D - Yes, "16".

Answer (score 5):

*Thanks to the forums over on raspberrypi.org I was able to find out the answer to this, so I am sharing it here for future reference...*

**ANSWER:** The 128M of GPU RAM is still being reserved because I have the Raspberry Pi Camera enabled.  The camera requires a minimum of 128M of GPU RAM to be held aside in order to function properly.  This overrides the `gpu_mem=16` setting in the `\boot\config.txt` file.

**Going Deeper:**

If you see this happening on your Pi, you can validate if it's the camera by going into the `\boot\config.txt` file and looking for the setting `start_x=1`.  If that setting exists, your camera is enabled (even if you don't have one connected!).  To turn it off, either set it to `start_x=0` or comment it out, then reboot.  You should see your GPU RAM allocation go back to whatever value you placed in the `gpu_mem` setting.  Of course, then you won't have camera access, but hey, that's the deal, right?

Good luck, and thank you all for your help!

Comment: THANK YOU so much, exactly what was wrong w/ my setup.